# Jaeger: Trace not found when sending span data via opentelementry grpc interface

Tags: python, grpc, open-telemetry, jaeger, open-telemetry-collector

I want to send trace data from an (pretty much) offline IOT device logs. Therefore, I want to write span data directly to Jaeger via the opentelemtry API. When I use the opentelemetry libraries

```py
resource = Resource(attributes={"service.name": "my_service"})
trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider(resource=resource))
otlp_exporter = OTLPSpanExporter(endpoint="http://localhost:4317", insecure=True)

trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(BatchSpanProcessor(otlp_exporter))

tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)

with tracer.start_as_current_span("foo", kind=SpanKind.SERVER):
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("bar", kind=SpanKind.SERVER):
        print("lala")
```

the service "my_service" appears spans and I see the span "foo".

When I directly write a span to grpc, the service name appears in jaeger as well as the span name "SpanName_lolo" but I get the message

> No trace results. Try another query.

The code, I use is the following:

```py
import grpc
import opentelemetry.proto.collector.trace.v1.trace_service_pb2_grpc as otelp_collector_trace
import opentelemetry.proto.collector.trace.v1.trace_service_pb2 as otelp_trace
import opentelemetry.proto.trace.v1.trace_pb2 as trace_pb2

class TraceClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.server_port = 4317

        # instantiate a channel
        self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
            '{}:{}'.format(self.host, self.server_port))

        # bind the client and the server
        self.stub = otelp_collector_trace.TraceServiceStub(self.channel)

    def call_trace(self, message):
        t = otelp_trace.ExportTraceServiceRequest()
        tt = t.resource_spans.add()
        attr = tt.resource.attributes.add()
        attr.key = "service.name"
        attr.value.string_value = "testapp2"
        scope_span = tt.scope_spans.add()
        scope_span.scope.name = "scope_name_lala"
        span = scope_span.spans.add()
        span.trace_id = bytes.fromhex("7bba9f33312b3dbb8b2c2c62bb7abe2d")
        span.span_id = bytes.fromhex("086e83747d0e381e")
        span.parent_span_id = b""
        span.name = "SpanName_lolo"
        span.start_time_unix_nano = int(time.time()*1000000-1000)
        span.end_time_unix_nano = int(time.time()*1000000)
        span.kind = trace_pb2.Span.SPAN_KIND_SERVER
        print(t)

        resp = self.stub.Export(t)

        return resp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = TraceClient()
    result = client.call_trace(message="Hello Server you there?")
    print(f'{result}')
```

What can I do to make the trace visible in jaeger?

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing service name in Jaeger it means the span was saved successfully. You can retrieve it by trace ID. If you're using search, you need to provide correct time range.